# Highcharts y-axis label floating issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in my project and facing an issue with the y-axis label in bar chart becoming misaligned. Please use the given code in jsFiddle to view the issue.

JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'                
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        opposite: true
    },
    {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        yAxis: 0,
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }, {
        yAxis: 0,
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
        name: 'Year 2008',
        data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
    }]
});});
```

Html code:

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: There is a notable lack of JSFiddle in this post. Hopefully that's intentional; you can use Stack Snippets, after all, if you really need the code-running bits. Should either take that part out or put in the link, though.

Comment: Well, for me its working: http://jsfiddle.net/nz8fuhx4/ so please replicate your issue as live demo.

Comment: created a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tarunchopra91/z5dy08bq/

Comment: You must add a `max` value for that y axis, or have values other than `0` in your series in yAxis `0` : http://jsfiddle.net/z5dy08bq/1/  I don't know the reason why this is happening when you have `0` values only.

Comment: Thanks, its working with this, but not able to find any reason for this issue.